# Does Recall make sense in 2-class classification task?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, precision-recall

I know that Recall= TP/ (TP+FN)

Suppose I consider recall values for different contexts of a classifier . In one context , I take classA as my positive class and classB as my negative class . In another context , I take classA as my negative class and classB as my positive class.

Let R1 and R2 values be recall values in these contexts

```
R1=TP1/(TP1+FN1)
R2=TP2/(TP2+FN2)
But TP2=FN1 and FN2=TP1
So R2=FN1/(TP1+FN1)
So R1+R2=1
```

What's wrong in this argument?[I feel that something is wrong because I saw  classifiers being evaluated using recall ].

Equivalently , If I am asked to compute recall of the classifier , is it R1 or is it R2 ? How do you decide

Answer (score 0):

To get a meaningful result, you need to evaluate *both* precision and recall. Evaluating either in isolation stands a good chance of evaluating the function poorly.

Recall is *only* at the ability to say that an item is in a class if it actually is. If you look only at recall (without looking at precision) it's trivial to get a perfect score:

```
bool ismember(item, class) { 
    return true;
}
```

Guaranteed to give 100% perfect recall *every* time. The problem is that its precision obviously *stinks* (in fact, its precision is 0--it can't reject items that aren't members of a group, because it never rejects *anything*.

Contrariwise, if we look at precision in isolation from recall, it's equally trivial to get a perfect result every time:

```
bool ismember(item, class) { 
    return false;
}
```

Precision is the ability to reject non-members and conclude that they're not members of the class. Since this says nothing is a member of the class, its precision score is always 100% perfect. Of course, it has the opposite problem: this time the recall is 0.

Summary: we need to look at *both* recall and precision to get a meaningful result.

Comment: I understand this . But my question is on completely different lines .. what I am saying is that if there is a 2-class classifier , we can measure the recall of the classifier w.r.t class A or class B . But I argued in the question that those values add up to 1 . So if you are trying to maximize one value of recall , the other value of recall obviously drops

Comment: @Percy123: No--as my answer points out, it's not only possible, but utterly trivial to get perfect recall for both.

Comment: So If I am given a 2-class classifier and I am asked to compute recall of the classifier , what recall do I compute? Is it R1 or is it R2 how do you decide

Comment: You'd typically compute a weighted average of the two. e.g., if TP1 is 40% and TP2 60% of the whole, the whole would be (R1 * 0.4 + R2 * 0.6)/2 (well, except that a geometric mean probably makes more sense than an arithmetic mean in this case).

Comment: Can you give any pointers in this direction ? (its just that , I am still wondering if this computation is a standard measure)

Comment: The standard measure (as I pointed to in my answer) is accuracy: `(true positives + true negatives)/population`. If you don't look at precision though, you're pretty much inventing your own path--I doubt much in the way of standard measures apply.